# Is it posible to listen to an MQTT server and publish with Websocket (endpoint) from our own server

Tags: python, django, mqtt, django-channels, asgi

I have got an mqtt consumer that listens to a topic and based on that, I used to send a response on another topic.
However now I would like to create a Websocket Secure wss endpoint where i could stream this processed information.
Could you tell me if it is possible to do that wth mqttasgi library, if yes how.

Here I leave the code of my consumer.

```
from mqttasgi.consumers import MqttConsumer
from mqtt_handler.tasks import processmqttmessage

import json

class MyMqttConsumer(MqttConsumer):

async def connect(self):
    await self.subscribe('application/+/device/+/event/up', 2)
    await self.channel_layer.group_add("stracontech", self.channel_name)

async def receive(self, mqtt_message):
    print('Received a message at topic:', mqtt_message['topic'])
    print('With payload', mqtt_message['payload'])
    print('And QOS:', mqtt_message['qos'])
    dictresult = json.loads(mqtt_message['payload'])
    jsonresult = json.dumps(dictresult)
    processmqttmessage.delay(jsonresult, mqtt_message['topic'])
    pass

async def publish_results(self, event):
    data = event['result']
    await self.publish("stracontech/procesed/"+event['result']['device_id']+"/result", json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'), qos=2, retain=False)

async def disconnect(self):
    await self.unsubscribe('application/+/device/+/event/up')
```

Pd: @Santiago Ivulich maybe you can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Websocket consumer you need to follow the [guide](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html) in channels.

An example:

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    groups = ["broadcast"]

    async def connect(self):
        # Called on connection.
        # To accept the connection call:
        await self.accept()
        # Or accept the connection and specify a chosen subprotocol.
        # A list of subprotocols specified by the connecting client
        # will be available in self.scope['subprotocols']
        await self.accept("subprotocol")
        # To reject the connection, call:
        await self.close()

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        # Called with either text_data or bytes_data for each frame
        # You can call:
        await self.send(text_data="Hello world!")
        # Or, to send a binary frame:
        await self.send(bytes_data="Hello world!")
        # Want to force-close the connection? Call:
        await self.close()
        # Or add a custom WebSocket error code!
        await self.close(code=4123)

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Called when the socket closes
```

Then on your asgi.py:

```py
import os
import django
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from my_application.consumers import MyMqttConsumer
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'integrator_mqtt.settings')

django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'http': get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": MyConsumer.as_asgi(),
        'mqtt': MyMqttConsumer.as_asgi(),
    })
```

I would recommend to use daphne as the protocol server for the service that listens and streams to websockets.